# Bash-Scripting arrays

Tags: arrays, bash

I am new to bash-scripting & trying to understand how things work. It's all a bit strange..

The following can be put into a script or entered into the shell:

```
declare -a A=("foo" "bar")
B=1
[ ${A[B]} == ${A[$B]} ] && echo "wTF" || echo ";)"
```

This gives me "wTF" on my debian squeeze & also on cygwin 1.7.11-1

So. Why does `${A[B]}` work?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:  I should have learned better than to argue with you after our last encounter!  Still, I like bash.  I like it a lot.

Comment: @thb: Each to their own!  But IMO, any language that requires `[` to be an executable in order to work is a language that sucks.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: But `[` isn't an executable, it's a builtin. (Granted, it's a deficient one -- the behavior of the `[[ ... ]]` notation is far superior -- but it's not as though changing your `$PATH` would suddenly break `[`.)

Comment: @ruakh: At least on CentOS (which is not a good start, admittedly), `which [` tells me `/usr/bin/[`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The existence of a program doesn't mean that Bash depends on it. Bash builtins supersede external programs. (It's possible to create an alias or shell-function wrapper for `which` to let it report things other than external programs, but most people don't bother with this, or at least, they don't bother making it very thorough. So `which` isn't reliable for the purpose you're putting it to.) If you rename `/usr/bin/[` to something else, you'll find that `[` in Bash will still work.

Comment: @violet313: `[` and `test` are both builtins; neither is an alias for the other. They *are* equivalent in all respects, however, except that `[` expects its last argument to be `]` (which it discards).

Comment: @ruakh: You're right, it does still work.  Oh well, I'll delete that chapter from my book on things I hate about Bash...

Comment: @ruakh, oops, deleted my comment after refreshing & reading the new arrivals. cheers dude you are a big help. i am soon about to post a new q about stderr; perhaps you will peruse, as & when..

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, instead of `which [` try `type -a [`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the *Bash Reference Manual*, §6.7 "Arrays"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays):

> Indexed arrays are referenced using integers (including arithmetic expressions […]) and are zero-based; […] ¶ The *subscript* is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a number greater than or equal to zero.

So in effect, `${A[B]}` means `${A[$((B))]}`. This is convenient when you want something like `${A[B-1]}`.

Arithmetic expressions are explained in [§6.5 "Shell Arithmetic"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic), which says in part:

> Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.

So, `$((B))` means `$(($B))` (except that the former is smarter about some things, e.g. using zero instead of blank as a default for uninitialized variables).

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason `A` works: [parameter expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22422) and [substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMSUBREF)

Comment: Ok. I read that. I still don't get it. Suppose I use the following indirection:  `C=B; echo "${A[$C]}"; echo "${$C}"` ?